# gitolite error after adding a repo in the goitolite.conf

Tags: gitolite

I am getting below error while trying to push `gitolite-admin` repo after adding a repo name in `gitolite.conf`.
Below is the error.
Cloning works fine and I have already pushed some of the pub keys to the repo.

```
open conf/gitolite.conf-compiled.pm.new failed: Permission denied<<newline>>
system() failed,gitolite compile,-> 6400
```

Whereas cloning and pushing works fine for testing repo.

Gitolite user is gitolite3 and apache user writes to it and the protocol which am using is http.

Not sure where exactly it is failing. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check the permissions of your gitolite directories. Everything needs to be owned by the 'git' user. To set it recursively across your installation: `chmod -R git /home/git`